# Modded 1.8.9 instance has many fps drops

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I just opened an instance of 1.8.9. I downloaded many mods(including Optifine) to help with Hypixel Skyblock, a Minecraft server. As the title states, I noticed many frame drops during my gameplay. If you need it, here are my device specs.

Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40Ghz
RAM: 24.0 gigabytes

I run a 64-bit Windows 10 system, and have an x64-based processor. Should I allocate more memory for Minecraft? Right now, I allocate 1024 MB of memory for my instance.

Here are a list of the mods I use if you need it.

ChatTriggers, 1.3.0-1.8.9

Danker's Skyblock Mod, 1.8.4

Fullbright, 1.2

Melody Mod, 1.1

NotEnoughUpdates, 1.7.3-REL

Optifine 1.8.9

SkyblockAddons, 1.5.5

Please help!

Comment: did you try removing all the mods and alllocating more ram?

Comment: sorry, but modded minecraft technical support is off-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1GiB of memory doesn't do much justice to your install considering you have 24 GB, I would crank it up to 2GiB, maybe even 4GiB. Also, there are a trillion Fullbright mods, you should be more specific.

*My opinion but I would use Patcher instead of Fullbright, also the Melody Mod is in a massive gray zone so I would remove it if I were you since you might get banned.*

Also FPS drops in Hypixel Skyblock are pretty common, with Patcher you can try using "Entity Culling" and also disabling some particles and doing some general optimizations

Comment: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/fullbright/files/2579022
That is the fullbright download page.

Comment: Yeah, considering that hasn't been updated in 3 years and is deprecated by the owner, I would use Patcher instead